# how can I animate the UINavigationBar background change on UIViewController push?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uinavigationbar

My app uses two different backgrounds for the UINavigationBar to indicate to the user what level in the hierarchy they're at. When I push a UIViewController that needs the second background it lacks animation, the background changes immediately as soon as the UIViewController is pushed. How can I animate this so that the background change fades as the view is being changed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but this worked for me:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.duration = 0.5;

[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 20, 44, 20)] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Place this inside your `viewDidLoad` method. You'll need to link/import the **QuartzCore** framework.

Comment: I've long abandoned this, but thanks for posting anyway. This may come in handy someday.