# Swap Out UINavigationController's View?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I’ve set a background image for my UINavigationController that I want to fade into a different image when I need it to.

I set the background image like this:

```
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundOne”]];
```

I’m trying to change it like this (I want it to fade in/out):

```
[self.backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundTwo”]];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.backgroundImageView duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:self.backgroundImageView atIndex:0];
} completion:nil];
```

I don’t see any change happening. Thoughts?

The following works to swap the backgrounds, but there is no fading animation:

```
[self.backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
self.backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundTwo"]];
[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:self.backgroundImageView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Have you given [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823068/how-can-i-animate-the-uinavigationbar-background-change-on-uiviewcontroller-push/16993080#16993080) a try? Rather than creating a new image view you can just fade the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
    - (void)switchBackgroundImageViewAnimated:(UIImageView *)newBackgroundImageView
    {
        [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:newBackgroundImageView atIndex:1];
        newBackgroundImageView.alpha = 0.0f;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f animations:^{
            newBackgroundImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                [self.backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview];
                self.backgroundImageView = newBackgroundImageView;
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! Don't I need to remove newBackgroundView from the superview after I set self.backgroundImageView?

Comment: No, you don't. These references point to the same object. If you remove newBackgroundImageView from view hierarchy, both (current and old) background views will disappear.