# How to change the background image of navigation bar with animation?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, uiviewanimation

I'm using the a known animation to all of us, animate to change navigation bar's background image with small delay to change it from translucent (I made it the default) to (the blue theme).

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5, 
               delay: 0, 
               option: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, 
               animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }, completion: nil)
```

but the animation didn't work, but the nav bar's background image changed successfully, I don't know why!!

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no code of changing color You are setting just background image with no Image.

Comment: @NiravD updated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` within the animation block e.g.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

**Update for changing the background image**

This code worked for me:

```
let animation = CATransition()
animation.duration = 0.5
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
animation.type = kCATransitionFade

navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your-image-name"), for: .default)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happened. ':(

Comment: Do you need to change the `backgroundImage` or can you just change the colour like in my example code above? I've not got the time to investigate now but here is an apparent Objective-C solution to this issue when changing the image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823068/how-can-i-animate-the-uinavigationbar-background-change-on-uiviewcontroller-push

Comment: `background Image`, and the the other answer with Objective-C didn't work!

Comment: I've added an update to my answer. See if that works for you (it works for me)